# hide/show div on scroll, within another scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navbar that becomes fixed at a certain height (done by cloning the original navbar-container and only displaying the clone after scrolling).

There is a div within this navbar-container (an advert) that I want to hide whenever the user scrolls down, and reappear on scroll up. However, I'm not having any success!

Basic HTML of navbar:

```
<div class="toolbar-container">
  <div class="nav-ad"> ... </div>
  <div class="toolbar"> link 1 • link 2 • link 3 ... </div>
</div>
```

My code that doesn't work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop()>0) {
    $('.cloned.nav-ad').fadeOut();
 } else {
    $('.cloned.nav-ad').fadeIn();
 }
});
```

jQuery for cloned navbar (a great solution from http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD to prevent it from jumping):

```
$('.toolbar-container').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.toolbar-container').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);
function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {

    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.
    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.

   orgElement = $('.original');
   coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
   leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
   widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');

  $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
  $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
} else {
  // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
  $('.cloned').hide();
  $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
}
});
```

Am I on the right track here? The advert and toolbar are both flexboxes. The links in the navbar display a dropdown on hover (which also works great). Just can't figure out the nav-ad!

Answer (score 2):

First you had mentiend a wrong selector to fade out , you missed spacing between the two classes so it should be like `$('.cloned .nav-ad')` .

Also if you want to fade (in/out ) depending on scroll you have to compare to the last `window.scrollTop()` value to show/hide your nav ad .

Bellow a working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.toolbar-container').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.toolbar-container').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();
  var scroll =0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   
   if ($(this).scrollTop()>scroll) {
      $('.cloned .nav-ad').fadeOut();
      scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   } else {
      $('.cloned .nav-ad').fadeIn();
      scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   }
  });
  
  scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);
  function stickIt() {
    var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
    orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {

        // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.
        // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.

       orgElement = $('.original');
       coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
       leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
       widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');

      $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
      $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
    } else {
      // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
      $('.cloned').hide();
      $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.toolbar-container {
  background-color:#02a;
  padding:5px;
}

.nav-ad {
  float:right;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h2>This is a banner</h2></div>
<div class="toolbar-container">
  <div class="nav-ad">ad goes here </div>
  <div class="toolbar"> link 1 • link 2 • link 3 ... </div>
  
</div>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p><p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
<p>parag parag parag parga</p>
```

Comment: @bibs does this helped you .

Answer (score 1):

Reasons to why your code doesn't work:

1. You're trying to select `.toolbar-container` before the DOM is loaded. Encapsulate your code in `$(function(){/* DOM queries here */})` to run it only after the DOM is ready.
2. Your code has a syntax error: there's an extra closing parenthesis on the last line. You can use your browser console to check your code for syntax errors.

As for your ad-hiding code, you're missing a space in your selector, as your `.nav-ad` is inside the `.cloned` element. It should be:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.cloned .nav-ad').fadeOut();
 } else {
    $('.cloned .nav-ad').fadeIn();
 }
});
```

However, let me explain why you should change up the code more. The way your code is written, is very inefficient. To optimize your code, consider the following:

1. Always initialize all your variables with `var`, `let` or `const`. Undeclared variables are implied to be global variables, which is very error-prone and in general a bad practice.
2. Don't use setInterval() for this operation. This is super inefficient. Use an `onScroll` event handler instead.
3. Don't give your elements classes to identify them. Instead, store them in a variable. This way you don't have to run new heavy DOM queries constantly.
4. Don't do the measurements that stay constant inside the event handler. Instead, measure once and store them in a variable outside the handler.
5. Don't call `.css()` multiple times on the same element consecutively. Instead, pass the function an object with all the styles you want to apply.

Here's a working code:

```
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $toolbarOriginal = $('.toolbar-container');
  var $toolbarClone = $toolbarOriginal
    .clone()
    .css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      marginTop: 0,
      zIndex: 500,
    }).hide().insertAfter($toolbarOriginal);
  var $adClone = $toolbarClone.find('.nav-ad');

  var orgElementPos = $toolbarOriginal.offset();

  $window.scroll(function(e) {
    $window.scrollTop() >= orgElementPos.top ? attach() : detach();
  });

  function attach() {
    $toolbarOriginal.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $toolbarClone.show().css({
      left: orgElementPos.left,
      width: $toolbarOriginal.css('width'),
      top: 0,
    });
    $adClone.fadeOut();
  }

  function detach() {
    $toolbarOriginal.css('visibility', 'visible');
    $toolbarClone.hide();
    $adClone.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Also, [here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pqLot29c/1/).

Furthermore, something to consider: most ad-blocking software automatically block elements with classes containing the word 'ad'.